# How to set iron-icon size inside paper-badge?

Tags: polymer

I have a `paper-badge` with an icon attribute set. I am able to change the size of the badge, but I also want to change the size of the icon inside it.

How can I do that? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<paper-badge>` currently doesn't support CSS properties to modify the icon's size (it's [hard-coded to 12x12](https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-badge/blob/9bd5751/paper-badge.html#L80-L83)). However, you could change icon's size in JavaScript by selecting the badge's `<iron-icon>` and setting its `style.width` and `style.height`:

```
// template
<paper-badge id="badge"></paper-badge>

// script
const icon = this.$.badge.$$('iron-icon');
icon.style.width = '20px';
icon.style.height = '20px';
```

```js
HTMLImports.whenReady(() => {
  Polymer({
    is: 'x-foo',
    attached: function() {
      const icon = this.$.badge.$$('iron-icon');
      icon.style.width = '20px';
      icon.style.height = '20px';
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.7.0/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="paper-button/paper-button.html">
  <link rel="import" href="paper-badge/paper-badge.html">
  <link rel="import" href="iron-icons/iron-icons.html">
</head>
<body>
  <x-foo></x-foo>

  <dom-module id="x-foo">
    <template>
      <style>
        paper-badge {
          --paper-badge-margin-bottom: -40px;
        }
      </style>
      <div>
        <paper-button id="btn">Status</paper-button>
        <paper-badge id="badge" icon="favorite" for="btn" label="favorite icon"></paper-badge>
      </div>
    </template>
  </dom-module>
</body>
```